# I want my onBlur handler to do something different if a certain button is clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a component A which receives focus and is passed an onBlur handler. I also have a button next to it. I want the onBlur for A to do something different if it is losing focus when the button is clicked instead of losing focus anywhere else on the DOM
How do I do this?

Comment: Show code that you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

You could check if the clicked DOM element that triggers the onBlur is the button or not, like this:

```
const ComponentA = React.createClass({
    propTypes: {
        onBlur: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    },

    componentDidMount: function() {
        document.addEventListener('click', this.onAnyClick);
    },

    componentWillUnmount: function() {
        document.removeEventListener('click', this.onAnyClick);
    },

    onAnyClick(event) {
        const container = this.refs.container;  // DOM element
        let isClickedOutside = true;  // initialization
        const eventTarget = event.target;  // DOM element
        let elem = eventTarget;
        while (elem !== null) {
            if (elem === container) {
                isClickedOutside = false;
                break;
            }
            elem = elem.offsetParent;
        }
        if (isClickedOutside) {
            this.props.onBlur(eventTarget);
        }
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
            <div ref="container">
                {/* component elements */}
            </div>
        );
    },
});

const Button = React.createClass({
    getElement: function() {  // public method
        return this.refs.element;  // DOM element
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
            <input ref="element" type="button" value="Click me" />
        );
    },
});

const ParentComponent = React.createClass({
    onComponentABlur(eventTarget) {
        if (eventTarget === this.refs.button.getElement()) {
            // do something if button was clicked
        } else {
            // do something else
        }
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <ComponentA onBlur={this.onComponentABlur} />
                <Button ref="button" />
            </div>
        );
    },
});
```